# Como cambiar el idioma a la barra de herramientas del ReportViewer Winforms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, report

Resulta que tengo una aplicación de Windows Forms y necesito que el idioma de la barra de herramientas del Report Viewer me salga en español y no en Inglés

[image: Barra de herramientas Report Viewer]

Gracias
Saludos

MI código es el siguiente donde armo el informe:

CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false);

```
        string report = "DALISF.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = report;
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(@"..\FORMATOS\", report);
        ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("Familias", Agregar);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
        ///<summary>
        /// Vista de impresión de la página
        ///</summary>
        reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
        // Esta linea que tenemos abajo sirve para rellenar toda la página en donde se muestra el informe
        reportViewer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ///<summary>
        /// Todo el ancho de la página
        ///</summary>
        reportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;




        //reportViewer1.PrintDialog();
        // Añadimos los parámetros que van a tener los reportes en cuestión (tenemos que ponerle los mismos nombres que tienen en el informe)
        mAnadirParametros("CodigoDesdeFamilia", DesdeCodigo);
        mAnadirParametros("CodigoHastaFamilia", HastaCodigo);
        mAnadirParametros("NombreDesdeFamilia", DesdeNombreFam);
        mAnadirParametros("NombreHastaFamilia", HastaNombreFam);
        mAnadirParametros("Infopie", "Para cualquier duda o consulta contacte con CTI Canarias. Tlf: 922 365 002 - info@cticanarias.com");
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportv); //Añadimos los parámetros al reporte.
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); // El informe se refresca cada vez que lo carga.

        reportViewer1.RenderingComplete += new RenderingCompleteEventHandler(RenderingCompleteEventHandler);
```

Comment: Probaste cambiar la cultura antes de generar el informe?

Comment: Si ya probé a cambiarla, pero no la cambia. Resulte que yo hice el informe con el visual studio , a la hora de depurarlo la barra de herramientas me salía en español, sin embargo, cuando lo abro ya compilado me aparece en Inglés.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta agregando el snippet de código donde armas el informe, de esa manera hay mas posibilidades de que alguien note donde esta tu problema

Comment: Modifica la pregunta, pega el código como texto, evita las capturas, es más difícil replicar tu problema, además de que quita posibilidades de que alguien encuentre la pregunta en un buscador

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo arreglé usando la interfaz **IReportViewerMessages** mediante la cúal implementamos la misma y tenemos diversas acciones para cambiar al idioma que deseemos la barra de herramientas del report viewer. Por aquí les dejo la documentación por si a alguien más le sirve:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/ms255036(v=vs.140)

Comment: Me alegro que hayas podido solucionar tu problema! si podes, deja un snippet de tu implementación para poder ayudar al próximo que tenga el problema!

Answer (score 0):

Deberias cambiar la cultura pero de toda la aplicacion, para eso en el `Main()` de `Program.cs` deberias agregar la linea

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

De esta forma defines la cultura de frma global para que afecte tambien a los controles

Comment: De esta manera tampoco funciona, a lo mejor puede ser algo de la .dll que viene predifinida en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Para que todos aquellos que tengan el mismo problema puedan solucionarlo, voy al poner el snippet con el código necesario para que funciona, en el idioma en que deseen.

Para ello vamos a una clase determinada en donde cargamos la interfaz. Para cargarla ponemos lo siguiente:

```
      public class CCustomMessageClass : IReportViewerMessages
    {
        public string BackButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Volver al informe primario"); }
        }

        public string BackMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string ChangeCredentialsText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string CurrentPageTextBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Página actual"); }
        }

        public string DocumentMapButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string DocumentMapMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string ExportButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Exportar"); }
        }

        public string ExportMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Exportar"); }
        }

        public string FalseValueText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string FindButtonText
        {
            get { return ("Buscar"); }
        }

        public string FindButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Buscar"); }
        }

        public string FindNextButtonText
        {
            get { return ("Buscar siguiente"); }
        }

        public string FindNextButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Buscar siguiente"); }
        }

        public string FirstPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Primera página"); }
        }

        public string LastPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Última página"); }
        }

        public string NextPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Página siguiente"); }
        }

        public string NoMoreMatches
        {
            get { return ("No se encontraron más entradas coincidentes"); }
        }

        public string NullCheckBoxText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string NullCheckBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string NullValueText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string PageOf
        {
            get { return ("de"); }
        }

        public string PageSetupButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Configurar página"); }
        }

        public string PageSetupMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Configurar página"); }
        }

        public string ParameterAreaButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string PasswordPrompt
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string PreviousPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Página anterior"); }
        }

        public string PrintButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Imprimir"); }
        }

        public string PrintLayoutButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Diseño de impresión"); }
        }

        public string PrintLayoutMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Diseño de impresión"); }
        }

        public string PrintMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Imprimir"); }
        }

        public string ProgressText
        {
            get { return ("Cargando"); }
        }

        public string RefreshButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Actualizar"); }
        }

        public string RefreshMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Actualizar"); }
        }

        public string SearchTextBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Buscar texto en informe"); }
        }

        public string SelectAValue
        {
            get { return ("Selecciona un valor"); }
        }

        public string SelectAll
        {
            get { return ("Selecciona todo"); }
        }

        public string StopButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Detener representación"); }
        }

        public string StopMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Detener"); }
        }

        public string TextNotFound
        {
            get { return ("No se han encontrado resultados que coincidan con el criterio de búsqueda."); }
        }

        public string TotalPagesToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Total de páginas"); }
        }

        public string TrueValueText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string UserNamePrompt
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string ViewReportButtonText
        {
            get { return ("Ver informe"); }
        }

        public string ViewReportButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Ver informe"); }
        }

        public string ZoomControlToolTip
        {
            get { return ("Zoom"); }
        }

        public string ZoomMenuItemText
        {
            get { return ("Add your custom text here."); }
        }

        public string ZoomToPageWidth
        {
            get { return ("Ancho de página"); }
        }

        public string ZoomToWholePage
        {
            get { return ("Toda la página"); }
        }

    }
```

Y luego a la hora de cargar el reporte con parámetros y demás le añadimos la interfaz que acabamos de añadir de la siguiente manera:

1º Implementamos  una instancia de la interfaz recién creada:

```
CCustomMessageClass myMessageClass = new CCustomMessageClass();
```

2º Para utilizarla lo hacemos de la siguiente manera (una vez que se añadan los parámetros al informe):

```
reportViewer1.Messages = myMessageClass;
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```